# nesting environment-variables on Windows

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I have a very simply (maybee very stupid) question regarding the Windows 7 (Path)-Variables.

Until Windows 10 the Gui looks very ugly und uncomfortable (short Textboxes for large Inputs) I Use custom variables to short down my view.

For example:
envi -->`C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;`

So I can use it in path like this:
path -->"`[...];%envi%;`"

Now I tried to do the same with the default settet part end extract the following:
sys --> `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;`

But THAT does not work:
path --> `;%sys%; %envi%; [...]`

even if I type "echon %sys%" it seems ok. But if I type "echo %path% it will resolve every variable instead of %sys%.

Now my question:
Is that impossible coursed by nested variables (%sys% contains %SystemRoot%?)
Or may there be another problem?

Greatings Oekel

Comment: Is it [this](http://superuser.com/questions/27826/why-cant-windows-handle-an-environment-variable-in-path)?